# Organize my bittorrent downloads?

Tags: macos, automation, bittorrent, transmission

I would like to organize my torrent downloads automatically into different target folders. Here's my setup, I'd like some ideas as to how to accomplish my aim.

I trigger new torrent downloads using Dropbox and Transmission on the Mac; I put my torrents in a torrents-only folder in my Dropbox that Transmission monitors, on a machine that is used just for this purpose, and automatically starts torrents.  Those torrents end up in ~/Downloads/Media

I would like, however, to have Transmission put, say, movies end up in ~/Downloads/Media/movies, TV shows end up in ~/Downloads/Media/TV, software in ... you get the idea.

I can obviously put my torrents in other folders, but Transmission only knows how to monitor one folder, and when it picks up torrents from that folder it only downloads to the default location.

How can I arrange this? I'm open to other torrent clients (although the Mac Mini is low-powered, so Vuze is not ideal (I used to write plugins for the app, so I was sad to stop using it in the first place)).

Comment: vuze headless?

Comment: It's a possibility, but I used to run it that way and it caused some sluggishness on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK command line torrent client, you can look into rtorrent.  You can specify multiple watch directories, and then [move the finished files based on the watch directory](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentCommonTasks#Movecompletedtorrentstodifferentdirectorydependingonwatchdirectory).

Comment: Is there a remote UI for it? Because right now it's pretty convenient to be able to check the status of my torrents in Transmission's web UI. The lack thereof is not a dealbreaker -- given that it's a command line app, of course -- but it's a downside.

Comment: There's not one by default, but someone built a web UI on top of rtorrent (http://code.google.com/p/avalanche-rt/).

However I run it inside GNU Screen and then ssh into the machine.